# como calcular edad de una persona con carbon en laravel?

Tags: laravel, carbon

Saludos tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$anios=\Carbon\Carbon::parse($paciente->fecha_nacimiento)->age;
```

Que básicamente me calcula bien la edad, pero esta edad se calcula con la fecha actual.

> Como calculo la edad para años anteriores o que recién llegaran?

Es decir calcular de edad de alguien que nacio el 1990 hasta el 2011 por ejemplo o de la misma persona nacida en 1990 hasta el 2046?

> Ademas, como calcular la edad de una persona recien nacida en meses?

por ejemplo: la persona nacio en septiembre de 2018 y calcularlo hasta enero de 2019?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CASO 1**

---

De esta manera puedes calcular la edad de una persona sabiendo cuando nació y usando la fecha actual

```
$nacimiento = "1989-04-06 06:00:00";
$actual = Carbon::now();

return $actual->diffForHumans($nacimiento, $actual);

//dará 29 años como resultado
```

**CASO 2**

---

Para calcular la edad de una persona dada su fecha de nacimiento y una fecha cualquiera diferente a la actual; funciona de este modo

```
$nacimiento = "1989-04-06 06:00:00";
$actual = Carbon::parse("2011-12-05 06:00:00");

return $actual->diffForHumans($nacimiento, $actual);

//dará 22 años como resultado
```

> Hacemos uso de `Carbon::parse()` para que la cadena que se le pase quede formateada a un formato de fecha válido.

**CASO 3**

---

Para obtener la diferencia de meses entre 2 fechas, pudieras hacer uso de `diffInMonths()` y construir tu código algo similar a esto

```
$nacimiento = "2018-09-01 06:00:00";
$actual = Carbon::parse("2019-01-01 06:00:00");
return $actual->diffInMonths($nacimiento);

//lo cual me dará la diferencia de 4 meses entre una fecha y otra
```

Answer (score -1):

CASO 4

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

```
function calcAge($birthdate)
{
    if (empty($birthdate)) {
        return 'Sin info';
    }

    $dob = Carbon::parse($birthdate);
    return $dob->age;
}
```

Comment: Buenas, José, bienvenido al sitio. Esto que planteas como caso 4 refleja el código original que aparece en la pregunta, en el cual se calcula la edad a partir de la fecha actual. Pero no es esto lo que se requiere.